# How can I combine multiple selectors result into one result?

Tags: jquery

I need to combine multi Jquery selector result into on consolidate result to apply common functionalities on all result.

Comment: use , to have multiple selectors like jQuery( "selector1, selector2, selectorN" )

Comment: @gopal , what is your purpose , what do you want to do exactly , please explain

Comment: You'll get more useful help if you post the code you've already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to combine multi Jquery selector result into on consolidate
>   result

You can use [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method, it adds elements to the set of matched elements.

```
selectReturnedColleciton2.add(selectReturnedColleciton1).somemethod()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in multiple selector syntax.

See: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

`$( "selector1, selector2, selectorN").some_method();`

Answer (score 1):

use [ADD()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .add() method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those
>   elements and the ones passed into the method. The argument to .add()
>   can be pretty much anything that $() accepts, including a jQuery
>   selector expression, references to DOM elements, or an HTML snippet.

example

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
</ul>
<p>a paragraph</p>


$( "li" ).add( "p" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```